# How can I explode a string by more than one space, but not by exactly one space in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a text line that is delimited by tabs and multiple spaces but not single spaces. I have found:

```
parsed = preg_split('/ +/', $line); // one or more spaces
```

which can a split a line with one or more spaces. Is there a regex for only more than 1 space but not exactly 1 space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `preg_split('/  +/', $line);` -- this is a blank followed by one or more blanks. Note that there are 2 blanks between the / and the +, even if it looks like one. Or, you could write it as `'/ {2,}/'`, which also means previous expression (the blank) repeated at least 2 times.

Comment: Stupid Editor breaks my expressions. The first is '/__+/', the second is '/_{2}/', with the _ denoting a blank.

Answer (score 2):

```
parsed = preg_split('/ {2,}/', $line); // two or more spaces
```

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace character (tabs, spaces, newlines). The OP requested to match multiple spaces.

Comment: Warning - \s can be a new line, carriage return, horizontal tab, vertical tab or just anything "space-like" as well.

Comment: Yikes! My mistake, sorry. I can't seem to re-edit my original comment, but I suggested that MrSlayer use the regex `'/\s{2,}/'` for readability

Comment: No need to be sorry, @RobM. Better to leave your comment for future visitors who might find that type of stuff useful.