# Reading data from a php file and displaying output

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like the code below to read from a file and output the result shown below

[image]

Text in text file is something like;

18:55, 16th April 2013  4 tires  1 oil  6 spark plugs  $477.4 22 Short St, Smalltown

Am getting error

```
    Warning: Undefined array key 1 in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\Chapter03\vieworders_v2.php on line 55

    Warning: Undefined array key 2 in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\Chapter03\vieworders_v2.php on line 56

    Warning: Undefined array key 3 in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\Chapter03\vieworders_v2.php on line 57

    Warning: Undefined array key 4 in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\Chapter03\vieworders_v2.php on line 65

    Warning: Undefined array key 5 in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\Chapter03\vieworders_v2.php on line 66
```

the script uses the function file(), which loads the
entire file into an array. Each line in the file becomes one element of an array. This code also
uses the count() function to see how many elements are in an array

The code is shown below;

```
    <?php
      // create short variable name
      $document_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Customer Orders</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        table, th, td {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 6px;
        }

        th {
          background: #ccccff;      
        }
        </style>

      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
        <h2>Customer Orders</h2> 

        <?php
          //Read in the entire file
          //Each order becomes an element in the array
          $orders= file("$document_root/Chapter03/orders.txt");
        
          // count the number of orders in the array
          $number_of_orders = count($orders);
        
          if ($number_of_orders == 0) {
            echo "<p><strong>No orders pending.<br />
                  Please try again later.</strong></p>";
          }
        
          echo "<table>\n";
          echo "<tr>
                  <th>Order Date</th>
                  <th>Tires</th>
                  <th>Oil</th>
                  <th>Spark Plugs</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                <tr>";
        
          for ($i=0; $i<$number_of_orders; $i++) {
            //split up each line
            $line = explode("\t", $orders[$i]);
        
            // keep only the number of items ordered
            $line[1] = intval($line[1]);
            $line[2] = intval($line[2]);
            $line[3] = intval($line[3]);
        
            // output each order
            echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$line[0]."</td>
                  <td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$line[1]."</td>
                  <td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$line[2]."</td>    
                  <td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$line[3]."</td>
                  <td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$line[4]."</td>
                  <td>".$line[5]."</td>
              </tr>";
          }    
          echo "</table>";
        ?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you post some lines from your file? Looks like `explode` is not finding the tab chars that you're telling it to look for.

Comment: what do you want for result expected as, from this data "18:55, 16th April 2013 4 tires 1 oil 6 spark plugs $477.4 22"

Comment: @RobRuchte that worked. The error was in the text file. The tabs char were wrong. I just di that and it worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20502218/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tabs in the data string that you posted, there are two space characters between the fields. That's not great, if you can fix that on the producer side that would be best. It not, you can explode on two spaces instead of a tab. I hope you never have multiple consecutive spaces spaces in the field values though...

```php
<?php
$str = '18:55, 16th April 2013  4 tires  1 oil  6 spark plugs  $477.4 22 Short St, Smalltown';
$arrRaw = explode("\t", $str);

assert(sizeof($arrRaw)==1, 'We expect only one element, because there are no tab chars in the string.');

$strTab = str_replace('  ', "\t", $str);
$arrTab = explode("\t", $strTab);
assert(sizeof($arrTab)==5, 'We expect 5 elements.');

echo 'Raw array:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($arrRaw);
echo PHP_EOL.'Fixed array:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($arrTab);
```